# JSONExcepton: No value for gps?

Tags: php, android, json

This is how i am generating JSON response.

```
if ($tag == 'test') {

        $json = array();
        $json["gps"] = array();
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT lats,longs,types  FROM wrdgps"); 
        if ($result)
        {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $tmp = array();        
            // $tmp["uid"] = $row["uid"];
            $tmp["lats"] = $row["lats"];
            $tmp["longs"] = $row["longs"];
            $tmp["types"] = $row["types"];
            array_push($json["gps"], $tmp);
        }
        //header('Content-Type: application/json');
        $response["success"] = 1;
        echo json_encode($response);
        echo json_encode($json);
        }

        else {
            $response["error"] = 1;
            echo json_encode($response);
        }


    }
```

This is JSON Response.

```
    {"gps":[
     {
     "lats":"33.23231833333333",
     "longs":"73.23232166666666",
     "types":"Road Blocked"
    }
   ]
   }
```

This is android end. In LogCat i am getting the complete JSON response but code only parsing KEY_SUCCESS = success, but not others TAG_GPS = gps, TAG_LATS = lats, TAG_LONGS = longs, TAG_TYPES = types. and throws an exception of JSONExcepton: No value for gps

Test.java

```
 public class Test extends Activity {

        /**


*  JSON Response node names.
     **/


    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_GPS = "gps";
    private static final String TAG_LATS = "lats";
    private static final String TAG_LONGS = "longs";
    private static final String TAG_TYPES = "types";
    private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
    JSONArray user = null;


    TextView tv1;
    TextView tv2;
    TextView tv3;
    Button test;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.test);

        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        test = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                NetAsync(v);
            }
        });


    }

    /**
     * Async Task to check whether internet connection is working
     **/

    private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask<String,String,Boolean>
    {
        private ProgressDialog nDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            nDialog = new ProgressDialog(Test.this);
            nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
            nDialog.setTitle("Checking Network");
            nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            nDialog.setCancelable(true);
            nDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args){


/**
 * Gets current device state and checks for working internet connection by trying Google.
 **/
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
                    HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                    urlc.connect();
                    if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                        return true;
                    }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return false;

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean th){

            if(th == true){
                nDialog.dismiss();
                new ProcessTest().execute();
            }
            else{
                nDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error in Network Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private class ProcessTest extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

        /**
         * Defining Process dialog
         **/
                private ProgressDialog pDialog;

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();


                    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Test.this);
                    pDialog.setTitle("Contacting Servers");
                    pDialog.setMessage("Getting ...");
                    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                    pDialog.show();
                }
                @Override
                protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {


                UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                JSONObject json = userFunction.test();

                    return json;


                }
               @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
               /**
                * Checks for success message.
                **/
                        try {
                            if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                                String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);

                                String red = json.getString(KEY_ERROR);

                                if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                                    pDialog.setTitle("Getting Data");
                                    pDialog.setMessage("Loading Info");


                                    String lat,lon,type;

                                    // Getting JSON Array
                                        user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_GPS);
                                        JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(0);
                                        // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                                        lat = c.optString(TAG_LATS);
                                        lon = c.optString(TAG_LONGS);
                                        type = c.optString(TAG_TYPES);
                                        //Set JSON Data in TextView
                                        tv1.setText(lat);
                                        tv2.setText(lon);
                                        tv3.setText(type);

                                        pDialog.dismiss();

                                    }

                                else if (Integer.parseInt(red) ==2){
                                    pDialog.dismiss();
                                }
                                else if (Integer.parseInt(red) ==3){
                                    pDialog.dismiss();
                                }

                            }


                                else{
                                pDialog.dismiss();


                                }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();


                        }
                    }}
            public void NetAsync(View view){
                new NetCheck().execute();
                }


}
```

Libraries
JSONParser.java

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSON", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

    }
}
```

Userfunctions.java

```
    public class UserFunctions {

        private JSONParser jsonParser;

        //URL of the PHP API
        private static String test_tag = "test";
        private static String testURL = "url";


        // constructor
        public UserFunctions(){
            jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        }

public JSONObject test(){
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", test_tag));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(testURL, params);
        return json;


       }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to parse json response properly by changing my code in to this.

```
      private static String url = "url";
      private static final String TAG_GPS = "gps";
      private static final String TAG_LAT = "lats";
      private static final String TAG_LONG = "longs";
      private static final String TAG_TYPE = "types";
      JSONArray user = null;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.test);
            Bt1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            Bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
                 new JSONParse().execute();
          }
        });
        }
        private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
           private ProgressDialog pDialog;
          @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);
                tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview2);
                tv3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview3);

                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Test.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
          }
          @Override
            protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
            JSONParser2 jParser = new JSONParser2();
            // Getting JSON from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            return json;
          }
           @Override
             protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
             pDialog.dismiss();
             try {
                // Getting JSON Array
                user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_GPS);
                JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(0);
                // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                String lat = c.getString(TAG_LAT);
                String lon = c.getString(TAG_LONG);
                String type = c.getString(TAG_TYPE);
                //Set JSON Data in TextView
                tv1.setText(lat);
                tv2.setText(lon);
                tv3.setText(type);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since KEY_SUCCESS isn't in the JSON output you posted, you obviously aren't giving us the full object.  That makes it a bit harder to debug.  But you're missing at least one level of getJSONObject calls here, since there is no KEY_SUCCESS available at the same level as the "gps" key, yet you're looking for them at the same level.  For a better answer, post your full JSON object not a partial one.

Comment: check now i posted my complete code for better understanding.